# File uploader for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project which upload multiple files so kindly if any one have the code of file upload then please share the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the jquery MultiFile script.
After adding the jquery and multifile script references to your page, you would then add a file input to your form and set the class="multi"

```
<input type="file" width="50" id="fileUpload" class="multi" runat="server" />
```

On postback, I iterate through the uploaded files and save them to a directory on the server or the cloud or wherever.

```
           for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Request.Files[i].ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    int retVal = saveFile((HttpPostedFile)Request.Files[i]);
                    if (retVal != -1)
                        documentID.Add(retVal); // documentID is a list of ID in my sql database. This code is located in a user control for document management.
                }
            }

    // note I have a few utility methods here...
    private int saveFile(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string directory = Server.MapPath(SiteRoot + UploadURL);
            string directory_filename_uploaded = directory + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            // make sure its unique so we don't overwrite.
            string directory_filename_unique = Document.GetUniqueFilename(directory_filename_uploaded);
            string filename_unique = directory_filename_unique.Substring(directory_filename_unique.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            file.SaveAs(directory_filename_unique);
            return insertFile(filename_unique);
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
```